# Makefile handling auto-generated source and Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, stm32, auto-generate, multiple-makefiles

I have a problem with a Makefile that's using an auto-generated Makefile to compile .o files from auto-generated .c and .s (assembler) source files.

The context is embedded programming for STM32 microcontrollers, where a Makefile and hardware initialization source code is generated from a hardware configuration file (.ioc file).

Suppose, we have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── archive
│   ├── a
│   │   └── a.c
│   ├── b
│   │   └── b.s
│   └── Makefile
├── Makefile
├── source
│   └── generate.sh
```

The files `archive/a/a.c` and `archive/b/b.s` may be empty here. My main `./Makefile` looks like this:

```makefile
.PHONY: default all clean generate objects

BUILD_DIR := build
SOURCE_DIR := source
OBJECTS := build/source/a/a.o build/source/b/b.o

default: all

all: objects

objects: $(OBJECTS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c $(SOURCE_DIR)/Makefile
    mkdir -p $(shell dirname $@)
    $(MAKE) -C $(SOURCE_DIR) BUILD_DIR=../$(shell dirname $@) VPATH=../$(shell dirname $<) ../$@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.s $(SOURCE_DIR)/Makefile
    mkdir -p $(shell dirname $@)
    $(MAKE) -C $(SOURCE_DIR) BUILD_DIR=../$(shell dirname $@) VPATH=../$(shell dirname $<) ../$@

$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c :: generate

$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.s :: generate

$(SOURCE_DIR)/Makefile :: generate

generate: $(SOURCE_DIR)/generate.sh
    cd $(SOURCE_DIR) ; bash generate.sh

clean:
    $(RM) -r build $(SOURCE_DIR)/Makefile $(SOURCE_DIR)/a $(SOURCE_DIR)/b
```

The `source/generate.sh` looks like this:

```bash
cp -r ../archive/. ./
```

In reality, this process much more complicated and takes a few minutes.

Finally, the `archive/Makefile` looks like this:

```makefile
BUILD_DIR := build

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    cp $^ $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.s
    cp $^ $@
```

In reality, we use `gcc` instead of a simple `cp` to compile the C and ASM source files.

The auto-generated `Makefile` uses `VPATH` to find the required input file and is actually meant to compile everything in a flat build folder (which I don't want).

I have no control over the contents of the auto-generated `Makefile`! The `source/generate.sh` should be treated as a black-box that I have no influence on.

Therefore, the superordinate `Makefile` has to slightly abuse the auto-generated `Makefile` by overwriting the `BUILD_DIR` and `VPATH` accordingly.

Now, if I first run `make generate` and then, e.g. `make build/source/a/a.o`, everything works as planned:

First, the `source` directory is populated with the auto-generated stuff, and then `build/source/a/a.o` is "compiled" from `source/a/a.c`.

However, if I don't run `make generate` first, I get:

```bash
$ make build/source/a/a.o
make: *** No rule to make target 'build/source/a/a.o'.  Stop.
```

My assumption was that the recipes would have been resolved in the following manner:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c $(SOURCE_DIR)/Makefile
    -> $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c: generate
        -> generate: $(SOURCE_DIR)/generate.sh
    -> $(SOURCE_DIR)/Makefile: generate
        -> generate: $(SOURCE_DIR)/generate.sh
```

After a bit of trial and error, I figured that I could somewhat fix this behaviour by defining the recipes as follows:

```makefile
$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c: generate
    true

$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.s: generate
    true

$(SOURCE_DIR)/Makefile: generate
    true
```

This yields:

```bash
$ make build/source/a/a.o
cd source ; bash generate.sh
true
true
mkdir -p build/source/a
make -C source BUILD_DIR=../build/source/a VPATH=../source/a ../build/source/a/a.o
make[1]: Entering directory '/[...]/source'
cp ../source/a/a.c ../build/source/a/a.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/[...]/source'
rm source/a/a.c
```

However, this leads to the `generate` step being run every time I run `make build/source/a/a.o`. Since the `generate` step is expensive in real life, this is not an option.

Also, `source/a/a.c` is treated as a temporary file that is meant to be deleted which I don't want.

How can I design my superordinate `./Makefile` so that the `generate` step is being run automatically, but only if necessary?

I also need to be able to build non-auto-generated source files from the root directory.

---

A few more strange `make` behaviours:

---

Simply running `make` (i.e. `make objects`) with this `Makefile` yields

```
cd source ; bash generate.sh
true
true
mkdir -p build/source/a
make -C source BUILD_DIR=../build/source/a VPATH=../source/a ../build/source/a/a.o
make[1]: Entering directory '/[...]/source'
cp ../source/a/a.c ../build/source/a/a.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/[...]/source'
true
mkdir -p build/source/b
make -C source BUILD_DIR=../build/source/b VPATH=../source/b ../build/source/b/b.o
make[1]: Entering directory '/[...]/source'
cp ../source/b/b.s ../build/source/b/b.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/[...]/source'
rm source/a/a.c
```

Why does `make` remove `source/a/a.c`, but not `source/b/b.c`? For the record: I want neither of these files to be auto-removed.

An issue that I am sadly unable to reproduce with my example is that `make` basically outputs the following line at the start (adpated to the example):

```
make: Circular source/generate.sh.c <- generate dependency dropped.
```

---

Changing the recipe to the following

```makefile
$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c: generate
    true

$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.s: generate
    true

$(SOURCE_DIR)/Makefile: generate
```

yields:

```bash
$ make build/source/a/a.o
cd source ; bash generate.sh
true
cc    -c -o source/Makefile.o source/Makefile.c
cc1: fatal error: source/Makefile.c: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: source/Makefile.o] Error 1
```

Why does `make` think that it needs to build a `Makefile.o` here?